# Function for determining difference between and start and end military time

Tags: functions

My apologies if this is the wrong place to post this question and/or it's stupid and I'm fine with it being closed/downvoted if it is.

I would like to know if there is a function that could be used to determine the difference between a start and end military time.

Something that could be applied generically to satisfy these equations:
1455 - 1450 = 5
1501 - 1450 = 11
1601 - 1450 = 71

Comment: You surely can express it as a complicated function, but it is better to see it as a program.

Comment: It's a real question. I don't agree to close it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe you guessed I'm a programmer?  I was hoping that there would be a way using division and modulus to "chain" things together for a generic formula but this would maybe be too complicated?  I wonder if there's a way to satisfy those equations with as few functions as possible?

Comment: A programmer's solution would be to use a library that understands time.  For instance, the python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) package includes a `timedelta` class to find the duration between times.  Otherwise you may get burned by corner cases like midnight, time zones, daylight savings time, etc. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang In my case, I'm only dealing with 1 day and not (yet) across multiple days so I have no need to deal with all that stuff.  If I did, I would most certainly use date and time libraries but I really only need to do math formulas.

Comment: Fair enough.  There is an underlying math question, for sure.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang not to mention leap seconds

Comment: Python implementation using a library (8 lines, including input and output) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127839/python-convert-military-time-user-input-and-calculate-time-worked-datetime-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent your military times as pairs $(h,m)$, where $h$ is an integer between 0 and 23, and $m$ is an integer between $0$ and $59$.  Then set
$$
    \Delta((h_1,m_1),(h_2,m_2)) = 60(h_1-h_2)+(m_1-m_2)
$$
This fits your three test cases, at least.  Another way to write this is
$$
    \Delta((h_1,m_1),(h_2,m_2)) = (60h_1+m_1)-(60h_2+m_2)
$$
which is the smart way to think about the process: convert to a “quantity” (seconds elapsed since midnight) and subtract.

Comment: This is nice but wondering if there's a way to take the entire time rather than (h,m)

Comment: @ZackMacomber $m$ is the remainder after dividing by $100$, $h$ is the (integer) quotient. In C (and many other programming languages), these are `t%100` and `t/100`, respectively. If you also have times that cross midnight, you’ll need do the hour subtraction mod 24.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting (wrongly!) the two digit sequences as decimal numbers $a$ and $b$, the duration is
$$ b-a-40\left(\left\lfloor \frac b{100}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac a{100}\right\rfloor \right)\ \text{minutes}.$$
For example,
$$ 1601-1450-40\left(\left\lfloor \frac {1601}{100}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac {1450}{100}\right\rfloor \right)=151-40\left(16 -14 \right)=151-80=71.$$

Comment: If I apply this with b=1455 and a=1450, I get 0